# Flutter pushReplacementNamed().then() does not trigger

Tags: dart, flutter

I am following this udemy course(https://www.udemy.com/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps) on flutter, and using scoped_model for state management.
I want to edit a product from list of products. For that I set the product id as a flag - selectedProductId in scoped model. When submitting, I want to navigate away and set this selectedProductId to null.

```
//method to edit product    
editProduct(productId, newValues);
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/productsPage').then((_){
   debugger();
setSelectedProductId(null);
}).catchError((err){print(err);});
```

The debugger is never hit. and there is no error either.

I tried using async await and still no use.

```
editProduct(editableProductId, _formData);
await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/productsPage').catchError((err){print(err);});
debugger();
setSelectedProductId(null);
```

the page is navigated to the given route, but the line after, is never executed. I even tried using `pushNamed` instead of `pushReplacementNamed`.

I know that `pushReplacementNamed` returns a future, so .then() must be called, but doesn't seem to happen, am I missing something? Are there any other factors or situations I should know?

Comment: the docs say: *"Returns a Future that completes to the result value passed to **pop** when the pushed route is **popped off** the navigator."*

Comment: I think the 'result' here is used to pass data to the replacing route. My problem is that the then callback is never triggered.

Comment: still did not get it. can you elaborate? preferably with an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got the concept wrong. Suppose you have `Activity A` and `Activity B`. From `Activity A` you navigate from `A` to `B`. Now the `then` from `A` is called only if `Navigator.pop(context)` is called from `B`. If `pop` is not called from `B` then the `then` callback is never called.

In your case you are calling `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` from `A`, so what you are doing is **REPLACING** `A` with `B`. So, even if you pop from `B` then `Activity A` is not available anymore, so the `then` callback will never be called.

You can refer to [this](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) section in the flutter cookbook for further info.

As for executing the code in `then` callback you should move it to `dispose` method of the `Widget`, you will see it getting called but I don't see the point in doing this because the `Widget` is getting destroyed and no point in setting its instance property as null.

Comment: the instance property is of the scoped_model I am using (model passed to this constructor). I was thinking that the callback is called on navigating itself. I shall have a refresher on navigation and get back on this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. If this answer satisfies your question then would be grateful if you gave an upvote and mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Accepted. Also, I wonder what is the point of .then() for this particular method `pushReplacementNamed`, when the callback is never going to be called. I mean why would flutter provide this?

Comment: It returns a future possibly to provide the `catchError` method because if the `pushReplacementNamed` fails then there is no error handling mechanism if this was not a promise. `then` is just what comes with `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Future Object might solve the Problem

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/product');
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 700)).then((_)=>resetSelectedProduct(null));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just simply add the below code:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/productsPage', (route) => false);
```